# jumbotron and its background image not responsive

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have applied a background image to jumbotron and there are 2 types of problems.

1) If I set the jumbotron to `height-auto` then the background-image height became very short but I need almost 500px height.

2) If I set the jumbotron to `height:500px` then it works but it is not responsive. When I open it on small screen-resolution the jumbotron height is 500px but the background image is responsive so that looks awkward.

Solution tried:

I used media query but it does not seem good to set media query at the different breakpoint.

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-custom img-responsive" style="background-image: url(img/bg2.jpg); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: I always try to ask it in a better way but you all guys are never happy. :/

Comment: Who said anything about being unhappy? I've voluntarely spent my time to provide an answer to your problem and try to help you - why are you being defensive when I try to assist you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am generally saying so not targeting you.

Comment: At the beginning SO can be a lilttle intimidating in regards to how well your questions/answers are perceived by the community, but as you get familiar with the standards and criterias what makes a good question/answer, you'll see it's not such a harsh place as it seems when you started ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can size the background-image to suit the div:

```css
background-size: contain;
```

To scale the background-image to cover the whole div:

```css
background-size: cover;
```

Here's an example:

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-custom img-responsive" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Leibniz-Einhorn.gif); background-size: contain; background-repeat:no-repeat;padding:100px">
some content
</div>
```

**Elaborate explanation:**

`background-size: auto auto;`

> The background image will retain its original size.
>   For example, if the image is 960px by 640px large. Its aspect ratio is 3 by 2. If it's bigger than its container it will be clipped.

`background-size: 120px 80px;`

> You specify a size in pixels, the first value is the horizontal size, the second is the vertical size

`background-size: 100% 50%;`

> You can use percentage values as well. Beware that this can alter the aspect ratio of the background image, and lead to unexpected results.

`background-size: contain;`

> The keyword contain will resize the background image to make sure it remains fully visible.

`background-size: cover;`

> The keyword cover will resize the background image to make sure the element is fully covered.